# What was the original Robocop's suit prop made of?

Tags: props, costume, robocop

Does anyone know what the Robocop's suit ***prop*** was made in the 1987 movie *Robocop*? Is it metal or just clothing like metal? When they were shooting the movie did the actor always wear the full suit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure how reliable the site is, but [Robocop Archive](http://robocoparchive.com/info/thesuit.htm) says:

> The outer shell of the RoboSuit (the armour) is constructed of
>   fiberglass. The interior segments (the black bits) are a combination
>   of high-impact plastics and foam rubber.

... while also saying that there are multiple versions of the suit.

> Altogether, seven complete robosuits were manufactured for the first
>   RoboCop movie. Some had specific functions, such as one required for a
>   scene in which RoboCop walks through an exploding gas station. **Special
>   fireproof fiberglass and other safeguards** were incorporated into the
>   suit worn by a stunt-man during the potentially hazardous shot. Two
>   additional robosuits - termed 'third act' suits - were also
>   manufactured. The third act suits reflects all the damage Robo had
>   suffered in his fight with ED 209 and when the Detroit Police
>   Department shoots him up. **Basically they just pulled pieces off the
>   molds for two fresh suits and then spent about a week using drills and
>   all kinds of tools to make it look like bullets had burned their way
>   through the armor.** Of course, a lot of thought went into it and the
>   bullet hits and gouges were very artistically placed. Finally, **about
>   thirty tygon tubes** were laid inside the suits and hooked up to all of
>   those bullet holes so they could have oil squirting out through the
>   impact craters.

Comment: So basically... a stormtrooper palette swap.